# Считать данные с CSV-файла в БД PostgreSQL. SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql, plpgsql

Всем привет, я незнаком с работой CSV файлов поэтому решил попросить совета (узнать) здесь как это работает. Работаю в PostgreSQL

```
COPY mark(id_p,mark,id_dis,date) 
FROM 'D:\bd2.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Есть у меня такой просто код, в котором я считываю данные с файла, а потом их СРАЗУ заношу в таблицу mark,но когда пользователь вносит данные и загружает их, он же понятия не имеет, что это за айдишники в таблице (у меня в табл. два айдишника), а вносит конкретные данные. И тут у меня БОЛЬШОЙ ВОПРОС.

Как мне считать данные с файла, но перед этим так сказать "обработать их", чтобы уже далее указать нужные для внесения в таблицу айдишники. Понятия не имею как в функции - это сделать......

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION csv_test( csv_name_f TEXT)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
BEGIN

COPY mark(id_p,mark,id_dis,date) 
FROM 'D:\bd2.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

END;
$BODY$;
```

Если у вас есть вариант как решить. Можете скинуть маленький пример, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: *Есть у меня такой просто код, в котором я считываю данные с файла, а потом их СРАЗУ заношу в таблицу mark,* Стрельба себе в ногу плоха тем, что когда-нибудь попадёшь. Неконтролируемые данные следует загружать во временную таблицу, а потом из неё уже раскладывать данные в боевые таблицы - при необходимости со всеми требуемыми проверками и преобразованиями.

Comment: @Akina В голове я понял как это сделать, но так как не работал никогда с временными таблица без примера не получается....
Понял, что сделать нужно примерно так: создать  временную таблицу и внести в нее данные из файла. Далее уже `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` 
Но пока не понимаю как в код это вообразить.

Comment: @Akina можете дать еще совет по моему новому ответу, который я добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем-то, у меня получилось. Не обращайте внимание на то, что так много данных (решил ограничения сделать...)

Также есть проблемка. Оно записывает только одну последнюю строку, а все предыдущие просто пропускает. Можно ли это как-то в цикле пройти ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test2(teach integer)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
BEGIN

DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS temp_table;
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table (
num varchar,
let varchar,
dis varchar,
last_n varchar,
oc varchar,
dt date
) on commit drop;

COPY temp_table(num,let,dis,last_n,oc,dt) 
FROM 'D:\bd2.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER encoding 'windows-1251';

insert into sch.ocenka (id_pupil,ocenk,id_discteacher,date)
 select 
sch.pupil.id_pupil,temp_table.oc,sch.discipline_teacher.id_discteacher,temp_table.dt 
 from sch.discipline_teacher,sch.discipline,sch.teacher,sch.class,sch.pupil,temp_table 
 where  sch.discipline_teacher.id_class = sch.class.id_class and sch.pupil.id_class = 
 sch.class.id_class and 
 sch.discipline_teacher.id_discipline = sch.discipline.id_discipline and 
 sch.discipline_teacher.id_teacher = sch.teacher.id_teacher and

 EXISTS (select * from sch.discipline_teacher 
 where sch.discipline_teacher.id_class = sch.class.id_class and
 sch.discipline_teacher.id_discipline = sch.discipline.id_discipline and 
 sch.discipline_teacher.id_teacher = sch.teacher.id_teacher and sch.discipline.title 
 =temp_table.dis and sch.teacher.phone=teach and sch.class.title =temp_table.num and 
 sch.class.kurs =temp_table.let) 
 and sch.discipline.title =temp_table.dis and sch.teacher.phone=teach and 
 sch.class.title =temp_table.num and sch.class.kurs =temp_table.let and 
 sch.pupil.last_name =temp_table.last_n;

DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS temp_table;
END;
$BODY$;
```